# IE caches and references old images for h:graphicImage

Tags: java, html, internet-explorer, jsf

I have an web application that uses JSF for form submission. I have a user select an image from a list followed by filling out and submitting a form. I then use the selected image and form input to annotate the image with the information. I then process a pdf file using the annotated images and email it to the user. After processing, I give the user the option to navigate back to the image selection page, or use the same images and go back to the form. Here is the jsf/html for the form that allows the user to navigate to their new page:

```
<h:form id="form" method="post">
    <div>
        <h:commandButton value="images" action="#{artwork.backToArt}"/>
    </div>
    &nbsp;
    <div>
        <h:commandButton value="Form" action="#{artwork.backToForm}"/>
    </div>
    &nbsp;
    <div>
        <h:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{artwork.backToUpload}"/>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

It seems that IE caches the annotated images and keeps those images on display regardless of my method calls.

Here are my methods:

```
public String backToArt()
{
    log.info("========= Setting back to art page ==========");
    this.backToForm();
    this.selectedValue = "";
    this.resizedArt = "";
    this.backArt = "";
    return "loginSuccess.xhtml";
}

public String backToUpload()
{   log.info("========= Setting back to upload ==========");
    this.backToForm();
    this.selectedValue = "";
    this.resizedArt = "";
    this.backArt = "";
    return "CSVSubmit.xhtml";
}

public String backToForm()
{
    log.info("============ Reseting all variables ==========");

    String temp = null;
    if (this.selectedValue != null)
    {
        temp = this.selectedValue;
        temp=temp.substring(temp.lastIndexOf(Dir.getDir("\\")) + 1, temp.length() - 4);
        this.selectedValue = temp;
    }

    log.info("Setting input variables");
    //set all previous values to blank
    //this.jobNum = "";
    this.quantity = null;
    this.headLine = null;
    this.codeNum = null;
    this.pass = null;
    this.expir = null;
    this.website = null;

    log.info("Setting front art to old image");
    //setting previous images to non-text
    if (temp.length() > 0)
    {
        temp = this.resizedArt;
        temp = "converted" + temp.substring(temp.lastIndexOf(Dir.getDir("\\")),temp.length() - 8) 
+ ".jpg";
        this.resizedArt=temp;

        log.info("Setting back art to old image");
        temp = this.backArt;
        temp = "converted" + temp.substring(temp.lastIndexOf(Dir.getDir("\\")),temp.length() - 8) 
+ ".jpg";
        this.backArt = temp;

        log.info("Deleting old text images");
        //start to delete text images
        File folderOne = new File(Env.textDestOne);
        this.deleteFiles(folderOne);
        File folderTwo = new File(Env.textDestTwo);
        this.deleteFiles(folderTwo);

    }

    log.info("============ Reset Complete ==========");
    return "FormSubmission.xhtml";
}
```

These methods reset the input variables and the images selected as well as deletes my annotated images depending on which button is pressed on that page. Looking at my logging, the methods are called and are processed, but no updating occurs for the images. When I process my pdf, the correct images and input are outputed, but what is viewed still shows old values. This means that my values are being stored properly and my methods are being called correctly. When I go to cancel and reprocess using Google Chrome, the images are updated properly.

Using all of this information, I have concluded that IE must be caching my images and not updating them with the correct values. I'm not sure how to override this, but I need to somehow clear the cache so that the images are updated to the correct values.

Edit: I noticed that when I refresh the page hitting F5, the pictures would update. Not sure what this means.

Comment: What does the HTML / JavaScript look like when it's inside a browser?  Can you test this with other versions of IE and maybe Firefox too?

Comment: I will install and test now actually. Good point.

Comment: Try to remove the attribute method from the <h:form /> tag.

Comment: Also check that the signature of the action methods is Object methodName()

Comment: Did both with no luck.